How can I know if "CreateFile()" opened a regular file, a device or a console handle?
Normally the Win32 API function CreateFile() opens a file given a path, but by specific formats of the path, it can also open console handles (e.g. CON) and devices: a volume (e.g. \\.\D:), a physical drive (e.g. \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE2), even tape (e.g. \\.\TAPE0). Unfortunately the given handle cannot always be treated as a regular file handle; for example, when opening a volume or a physical drive, trying to use GetFileSize() fails with "The parameter is incorrect". It needs DeviceIoControl(). And with a console handle, both GetFileSize() and DeviceIoControl() may not even make sense.
Is there a way to know if the function CreateFile() opened a regular file, a device or a console handle? Without checking the path beforehand.

Depends exactly on "what" is or 'what' you're after. You can use GetFileInformationByHandleEx (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getfileinformationbyhandleex) and see if there's what you're looking for

@SimonMourier, I will take a look. That is a lot of options. Thank you.

but you pass to CreateFile not random string but some path. from where/how you get/format it ? for what you need open file on device ? what you want do with file next ?

@Schilive Also have a look at GetFileType()

@RbMm, in the thing I am working, the users passes the path. It opens the path and reads it as a FAT formatted volume. It is meant mostly for regular files, but it would be really cool if it took advantage of Windows' device paths to also read volumes and physical drives.

@RemyLebeau, the function ´GetFileType()returnedFILE_TYPE_DISKfor regular files, volumes and physical drives. So I cannot use it do differ between these three, but it is helpful to prevent using console handles, which returnFILE_TYPE_CHAR`.

@Schilive but it would be really cool if it took advantage of Windows' device paths to also read volumes and physical drives. i dont understand what you try to say and in what problem. you simply do what need to do. or show error to user if some action fail. or what need ? i be say you need ask question in another way about something else

@RbMm, it is probable. The current problem is I am trying to get the file/device's size, but files need GetFileSize() and devices need DeviceIoControl(). So I need to know whether the user input path was a device or a regular file. Also, it seems my gift is not communication...

You could try to use GetFileAttributesA function to get the properties of the file. The devices have the specific property: FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DEVICE.

@Jeaninez-MSFT, I have tried GetFileAttributes("\\\\.\\D:"), but returned an error with the the message "The parameter is incorrect".

simply call GetFileSize or NtQueryInformationFile with FileStandardInformation. if error returned - call IOCTL_DISK_GET_DRIVE_GEOMETRY_EX or IOCTL_DISK_GET_LENGTH_INFO

@RbMm, yeah, that seems like a fine solution. I was hoping there was a more guaranteed/idiomatic way to determine the "file type". Because, e.g., both functions may fail if CON is given, and I cannot really say always say the "file" is the wrong type if both functions fail; because I tried to open my CD/DVD drive (\\.\F:), and it returned an error with the message "The device is not ready", which would be a useful message to give the user. I think I am gonna limit paths which start with \\.\ , treat \\.\Volume{GUID} as a special case, and treat everything else as a regular file.



Maybe it is the case that if GetFileTpye() returns FILE_TYPE_DISK and GetFileSize() does not work, it is necessarily a device, so DeviceIoControl() IOCTL_DISK_GET_LENGTH can be trusted to be the correct function to use, and so its error can be logged to the user.



file can be on any device. simply try got file size via FileStandardInformation and IOCTL_DISK_GET_DRIVE_GEOMETRY_EX . if both way failed - you have not filesystem or disk device

@RbMm, yeah, but it would be nice if I could log the user the error of DeviceIoControl()
"The device is not ready" (No CD in the drive) when they gave "\.\F:" (CD/DVD drive), but still could tell the user the given "file" is neither a filesystem nor a disk drive if they gave, for example,"CON". All though, if there is no CD in the CD drive, the message "Bad file type given" still looks reasonable.

NtQueryVolumeInformationFile with FileFsDeviceInformation and check FILE_FS_DEVICE_INFORMATION.DeviceType probably the best what you can do here

@RbMm, yeah. Thank you a lot for your answers! I will take a look at that function.
